# Read xls file using PHPExcel lib and get cell type

Tags: php, phpexcel

I read XLS file using PHPExcel. There is cells date column. that data column has two type of cells (Date and Text type cells).

I need to get view value of the cells in the XLS file. So before get value of the cell i want to decided whether that cell is Date cell or Text cell.

How can i get view value of the XLS file cells. Is There method like getCellType(), getViewValueOfCell() or any other method for get view value of cell?

Note: `$cell->getType` is not a real method in PHPExcel. this pseudo method.

please suggest best logic/method for bellow cell read.

```
 // read view value form date column
 if($cell->getType == 'Date'){
  $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($cell->getCalculatedValue(), 'YYYY-MM-DD'); 
 }
 else if($cell->getType == 'Text'){
  $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
 }
```

this my all XLS read function

```
       $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
   $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
   $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file_path);
   $rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();

   $array_data = array();
   foreach ($rowIterator as $row) {
      $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
      $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
      // if(1 == $row->getRowIndex ()) continue;//skip first row
      $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
      $array_data[$rowIndex] = array('A' => '', 'B' => '', 'C' => '', 'D' => '');

      foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
         if ('A' == $cell->getColumn()) {
            $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
         } else if ('B' == $cell->getColumn()) {
            $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
         } else if ('C' == $cell->getColumn()) {
            // read view value form date column
             if($cell->getType == 'Date'){
              $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($cell->getCalculatedValue(), 'YYYY-MM-DD'); 
             }
             else if($cell->getType == 'Text'){
              $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
             }
         } else if ('D' == $cell->getColumn()) {
            $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The cell's getDataType() will return the datatype of the value contained in a cell

Valid datatypes are defined in PHPExcel_Cell_DataType:

```
const TYPE_STRING2  = 'str';
const TYPE_STRING   = 's';
const TYPE_FORMULA  = 'f';
const TYPE_NUMERIC  = 'n';
const TYPE_BOOL     = 'b';
const TYPE_NULL     = 'null';
const TYPE_INLINE   = 'inlineStr';
const TYPE_ERROR    = 'e';
```

Note that there is no datatype for dates or times: dates/times are a datatype of float in MS Excel.

To identify whether a cell contains a date/time value you need to check the numberformat mask. To simplify this, the following methods are available in the PHPExcel_Shared_Date class to identify a numberformat mask as one that relates to a date/time

isDateTime()

```
/**
 * Is a given cell a date/time?
 *
 * @param    PHPExcel_Cell  $pCell
 * @return   boolean
 */
```

isDateTimeFormat()

```
/**
 * Is a given number format a date/time?
 *
 * @param    PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat    $pFormat
 * @return   boolean
 */
```

isDateTimeFormatCode()

```
/**
 * Is a given number format code a date/time?
 *
 * @param    string $pFormatCode
 * @return   boolean
 */
```

The API documentation should have identified these for you

Comment: I am currently experimenting with PHPExcel v1.8.1 and PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime() returns false even for cells containing date. Do not rely on this function.

Comment: @Pontiac_CZ - You aren't (for some reason) loading files with readDataOnly set to true are you? The function works perfectly well, as long as the format mask used to differentiate date/time values from floats is accessible... if you haven't allowed PHPExcel to load those format masks, then it will fail

Comment: @Pontiac_CZ And rather than simply posting warnings to spread FUD among people reading this, why don't you raise a bug, with a working demonstration of the problem, and then it might even get fixed... surely fixing a problem rather than simply moaning about it benefits everybody

Comment: You are right, I am using setReadDataOnly(). And I see now there is a note about this in User Documentation. I read it before but when you don't need it you ignore it. :-)

Comment: The PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime() should generate some sort of warning or maybe even exception when used on a cell without the format mask. I'll post an issue to their Github.

Comment: Caveat on that.... cells always have a format mask, because they default to the "General" mask if none is explicitly defined, or the data is loaded without one